# drawRect and tabBar (iphone iOS 4)

Tags: iphone, ios4, uitabbarcontroller, drawrect

I works on a iPhone app with a tabBar, two tabBarItem and two View.

I the first View i make some calculations, in the second View I draw some graphics with results of first View. When I call the SecondView for the first time all works fine (because I have a setNeedsDisplay in viewDidLoad), but when I need to redraw the content because some information (inside the FirstView) are changed nothings append.

In other words, the first time the second View drawRect is called, then is no more called.

In the AppDelegate I have a method

```
 - (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController 
                 didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

that perhaps can be used, but I cannot how to call it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call `- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController 
                 didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController`, add `<UITabBarControllerDelegate>` next to NSObject (or whatever subclass you have) in your AppDelegate.h.

Also call `tabBarController.delegate = self;` in your `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`.